# Multiple database inserts with Ajax with a dynamic number of textfields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to insert the multiple lines of a text field to my database.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>


<body>                      
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name[0]" name="name[0]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="grade[0]" name="grade[0]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name[1]"   name="name[1]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="grade[1]"  name="grade[1]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name[2]"   name="name[2]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="grade[2]"  name="grade[2]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name[3]"   name="name[3]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="grade[3]"  name="grade[3]"></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>

        <input type="button" id="submit_in" name="submit_in" value="submit">

</body>
</html>
```

I put index to my id so that I can loop it using Ajax but I don't know how to loop it and insert it using Ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_in').click(function() {

            var stud_name = $('#name[0]').val();
            var stud_grade =  $('#grade[0]').val();

            alert(stud_name+" "+stud_grade);

            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"insert.php",
                dataType:'json',    
                data:{'name':stud_name,'grade':stud_grade},
                success:function(data){

                }
            });



        });
    });

</script>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$host = 'Localhost';
$username= 'root';
$password= '12345';
$db_name = 'multiple_ajax';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("Cant Connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Cant Select DataBase");

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


$name= $_POST['name'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];   

    $insert = "INSERT INTO stud_info VALUES('$name','$grade')";

    if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
        die('error insert'.mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

My PHP code has only two variables that would get using Ajax because I suppose that Ajax will loop that variables using the index in id. I'm new to Ajax and PHP

Comment: Would one Ajax request with looping on the PHP side be acceptable?

Comment: yes it would be acceptable. still out of luck doing my trials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you know that you can pass arrays through HTTP requests, right? Why are you doing requests one at a time? Concatenate all of them!

```
var GradeData = [];
$("table > tr").each(function() {
   var k = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
   if (k.length == 2) {
      GradeData.push({ "name": k.eq(0).val(), "grade": k.eq(1).val()});
   }
});
```

You will then have an array `GradeData` with each element having a name and a grade. To pass it through AJAX, do it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "insert.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {
     students: GradeData
  }
});
```

And from there, it's a simple matter to recover it using PHP (it'll come up as `$_POST['students']` and the format of each element of the array will always be Array('grade' => 'something', 'name' => 'something'). From there, you just need to iterate and...that's it!

From there, inserting the rows is equally easy:

```
<?php
$host = 'Localhost';
$username= 'root';
$password= '12345';
$db_name = 'multiple_ajax';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("Cant Connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Cant Select DataBase");

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
foreach ($_POST['students'] as $data) {
    $name= $data['name'];
    $grade = $data['grade'];   
    $insert = "INSERT INTO stud_info VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."')";

    if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
       die('error insert'.mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: im stuck on thinking how im going to separate the name and grade when its already in php bcuz you're only using one variable to pass name and grade  data: {students: GradeData } how will i put it in insert?

Comment: By looping over it? Use a foreach loop to go over $_POST['students']. Something like foreach ($_POST['students'] as $studentInfo) { }. Inside the loop, $studentInfo['name'] is the name, and $studentInfo['grade'] is the grade!

Comment: am i doing this right? $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit_in').click(function() {


    var GradeData = [];
    $("table > tr").each(function() {
       var ggrade = $(this).find(".gradetxt");
       var nname = $(this).find(".nametxt");


       for(var i=0; i <= ggrade.length; i++){

          GradeData.push({ "name": nname.eq(i).val(), "grade": ggrade.eq(i).val()});

       }


    });


    $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"insert.php",
     dataType:'json', 
     data:{'name':GradeData},
     success:function(data){

     }
    });



   });
  });

Comment: Yes, but that means that you'll recover the non-associative array in PHP as `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: so im going to make 2 foreach for grade and names?

Comment: Don't! They're both contained in GradeData! Look at the code!

Comment: still stuck on how am i going to do it.. still confused

Comment: Editing my answer with a PHP snippet.

Comment: im stuck with this $studnt_info = $_POST['students'];


 $to_id = explode(',', mysql_real_escape_string($studnt_info));

   
        $insert = "INSERT INTO stud_info VALUES('$name','$grade')";

dont have an idea on how am i going to put it inside a foreach

Comment: I've added a PHP snippet to my answer .Have you seen it?

Comment: Corrected: http://pastebin.com/cVtXerN3 . Your error was in JavaScript. I have no idea why you were looping using a for loop when you were looping already using jQuery selectors.

Comment: still not working i though i copied the whole code of yours http://pastebin.com/2kvSFUKB

Comment: My apologies. Change $("table > tr") to $("table tr"). I keep fogetting that some browsers now surrepticiously add <tbody> tags inside tables.

Comment: tnx men it helps a lot.. later ill try not to depend on the table to get all the data